# Static and dynamic bindning

Tags: inheritance, dynamic, static, polymorphism, encapsulation

I have tried to find information on the internet but I have not got a clear picture of it. 
My question is what affect static and dynamic binding have on encapsulation, inheritance, subtype polymorphism in object orientated programming?